# High hydration breads end up with gummy/undercooked interior

Tags: baking, bread, dough

Whenever I make bread with hydration from 80%-120% the interior is always gummy and undercooked. They have a decent hole structure, but collapse easily when pressed.

I typically use

Whole Wheat Chakki Atta or Maida
Filter Water
Instant dry yeast (1 tsp per kg of flour)
Salt

Following recipes like  https://www.weekendbakery.com/posts/recipe-for-80-hydration-baguette/

Tried kneading (by hand), no knead, normal rise, refrigerator rise, varying rise/rest durations etc. all with similar results. Atta breads are gummier.

Answer (score 3):

Bake to 205° F interior temperature. Excess ß-amylase enzyme can also cause gummy.

Comment: I tried this with chakki atta. Was facing the same issue. This works!!